# Oracle JSON_ARRAYAGG returns duplicate JSON_OBJECTs

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Need to create a Json_Object which can contain multiple nested Json_objects, Json_arrays & Json_arrayaggs within .

I have Created this table with some dummy data to demo the problem:

```
create table test_tbl(
test_col1 varchar2(20), 
test_col2 varchar2(20), 
test_col3 varchar2(20),
test_col4 varchar2(20)
);
insert into test_tbl values('val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val7');
insert into test_tbl values('val0', 'val3', 'val4', 'val7');
insert into test_tbl values('val0', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7');
insert into test_tbl values('val0', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7');
insert into test_tbl values('val0', 'val5', 'val6', 'val8');
insert into test_tbl values('val1', 'val9', 'val10', 'val7');
insert into test_tbl values('val1', 'val9', 'val10', 'val7');
```

When Using following query to create Json:

```
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT ( 'output' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('common' VALUE test_col1, 'list' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('key1'
    VALUE test_col2, 'key2' VALUE test_col3)))) )
FROM
    test_tbl
WHERE
    test_col4 = 'val7'
GROUP BY
    test_col1
```

This results in following json with duplicate key, value pairs in the aggregated array -

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "common": "val0",
      "list": [
        {
          "key1": "val5",
          "key2": "val6"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val5",
          "key2": "val6"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val3",
          "key2": "val4"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val1",
          "key2": "val2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "common": "val1",
      "list": [
        {
          "key1": "val9",
          "key2": "val10"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val9",
          "key2": "val10"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Whereas my expected Json is :

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "common": "val0",
      "list": [
        {
          "key1": "val5",
          "key2": "val6"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val3",
          "key2": "val4"
        },
        {
          "key1": "val1",
          "key2": "val2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "common": "val1",
      "list": [
        {
          "key1": "val9",
          "key2": "val10"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to get the expected Json above.

Comment: Your question is clear. It is not clear, however, if you understand why you are getting the current result from the current query. Your question is similar to this: "3 + 5  + 5 + 1 produces the result 14, but I expect the result 9" (you don't want 5 to be counted twice). In your data you have duplicate values by `val1, val2, val3`; all that `json_arrayagg` does is to collect its inputs and create an array from them - there is no task to eliminate duplicate members. An array may validly contain repeated values.

Comment: In fact, if such duplicates may exist in the input, it is not clear why you want them removed in the output.

Comment: i agree that json_arrayagg is working to the spec. However, the dataset i am working with is not normalized, it's all just dumped into this huge table with lots of duplicate data. I am trying to remove the duplicates when creating a json from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query with `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
         'output' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             'common' VALUE test_col1,
             'list'   VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 'key1' VALUE test_col2,
                 'key2' VALUE test_col3
               )
             )
           )
         )
       )
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         test_col1, test_col2, test_col3
  FROM   test_tbl
  WHERE  test_col4 = 'val7'
)
GROUP BY
       test_col1
```

Comment: On further testing, Above solution works if there is one list in the output, if there are 2 lists, each with duplicate elements, then it starts to produce duplicate key, value pairs within each list.I am not sure if I should update the post above or raise a new one for this problem

Comment: If there are 2 more columns - test_col5 varchar2(20),
test_col6 varchar2(20). With values : insert into test_tbl values('val1', 'val9', 'val10', 'val7','val11', 'val12'); insert into test_tbl values('val1', 'val9', 'val10', 'val7','val13', 'val14');And following additional node as a sibling to 'list': 'anotherlist' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT('key1' VALUE test_col5,  'key2' VALUE test_col6 )).

Comment: @Oten That seems like a very different problem if you have two lists in the same table and want to aggregate the distinct values from each. If you want a complete answer then you should ask a new question but it'll probably just be to `SELECT DISTINCT` from the first list and aggregate and then `SELECT DISTINCT` from the second list and aggregate and then `JOIN` the two lists on their shared primary key (and to question why you are storing the data like that rather than in different tables).

Comment: This data is from a third party app and I am trying to remove duplicates when creating the json. Created this new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610906/how-to-aggregate-distinct-values-from-multiple-lists-using-oracle-json-object